# Total number of sequences for tossing a fair coin at most 10 times.

Tags: combinatorics

How do I count the total number of possible sequences for tossing a fair coin for at most 10 times? This needs to be done without a computer, so I'm wondering if there is some kind of shortcut like a formula. For instance, how would I find the total if I get this question on a test where my only aid is a calculator?

A couple examples of possible sequences:

HTTHH

TTHTHHH

Comment: Try to find out the number of sequences of exact length $k$ noting that each place can either have head or tails.

Comment: For each $n \in \{1,2, \ldots ,10\}$ the number of T-H sequences is $2^n$. You want $\sum_{n=1}^{10} 2^n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

How many sequences are there for tossing a fair coin once?

How many sequences are there for tossing a fair coin twice?

...

How many sequences are there for tossing a fair coin ten times?

Another hint:

$$\sum_{j=1}^n 2^j = 2^{n+1} - 1$$